# Load an external image inside of an SVG

Tags: image, svg, external

Is it possible to have a browser load an image from an external resource inside of an SVG? The SVG itself displays but the referenced image displays as a broken image. Is there any way to convince the browser that it should display this image?

Comment: Depends how you're using the SVG. If it's like an image then no, if not I.e. inline or via an object or iframe then yes.

Comment: Add some of your code to the question. How are you displaying the SVG -- in a HTML page -- and how is that done?

Comment: Yes, it's loading an SVG inside of an `<img>` tag and then it has an `<image>` inside of the SVG, so it's not inlined